# Exception in mapreduce code which is accessing Hbase table java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/google/protobuf/HBaseZeroCopyByteString

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

Hi getting the following exception, when running the map reduce program. The code has access to Hbase table and doing Put operation.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/google/protobuf/HBaseZeroCopyByteString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because, while trying to run the map reduce job, the hadoop class path is missing hbase-protocol.jar. So adding this before running the map reduce will remove the error.

```
$export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol.jar; hadoop jar <jar_path>/<yourjar_name>.jar <inputPath> <outputPath>
```